# Please solve a problem with selectorlib, get this message but can not uderstand it

Tags: python, web-scraping, selector

inside main file code

```
import requests
import selectorlib


URL = 'http://programmer100.pythonanywhere.com/tours/'
HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

def scrape(url):
    response = requests.get(url,headers=HEADERS)
    source = response.text
    return source
def read(extracted):
    with open("data.txt",'r') as file:
        return file.read()
def extract(source):
    extractor = selectorlib.Extractor.from_yaml_file("extract.yaml")
    value = extractor.extract(source)['tours']
    return value


def send_email():
    print("Email send")

def store(extracted):
    with open("data.txt",'w') as file:
        file.write(extracted+'\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scalped = scrape(URL)
    extracted = extract(scalped)
    print(extracted)
    store(extracted)
    content = read(extracted)
    if extracted != "No upcoming tours":
        if extracted not in "data.txt":
            send_email()
```

```
_________________________________________________
----error
/usr/local/bin/python3.12 /Users/admin/Desktop/CV/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/CV/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    extracted = extract(scalped)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/CV/main.py", line 18, in extract
    value = extractor.extract(source)['tours']
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selectorlib/selectorlib.py", line 74, in extract
    fields_data[selector_name] = self._extract_selector(selector_config, sel)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selectorlib/selectorlib.py", line 78, in _extract_selector
    if field_config.get("xpath") is not None:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Help please to understand the problem, why i always get this error

i am try fixing this problem.  I am try to get selector but it's always show message

---

this inside extract.yaml file

```
tours:
  css:'#displaytimer'
```

-------------This is all my code-----

Comment: `"extract.yaml"` isn't a valid YAML string; it looks like the name of a file, that might perhaps *contain* YAML data.  You probably want `from_yaml_file()` instead of `from_yaml_string()` here.

Comment: yes i am change but the same proble

Comment: _Show us_. Don't just assert that the problem still occurs after you correct your code -- _edit the question_ and replace the code and the error with the _exact_ error you get _after_ the update.

Comment: (If it really does still happen after you fixed that, we'll probably also need to see the contents of the `extract.yaml` file. Note [mre] guidelines -- a question should contain the shortest possible code that causes the same problem when run without any changes; needing to have a copy of your config file is a change, and a thing without which nobody else can run your code).

Comment: you need to show/include in the question the content of `extract.yaml` file. Also: `tours` in the source of the page exist only as ` <a class="nav-link" href="/tours/">Tours</a>`

Comment: show all my code from all file

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming due to small format issue in the YAML file.
You need to provide space after `:` in yaml file.
Like

```
tours:
  css: '#displaytimer'
```